# Template type deduction in parameter and return type

Tags: c++, c++17

in our current code base we have code that looks something like the below (this is of course a simplified version):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// General template function to convert an enum to a string, given a converter-container
// The converter-container is either a map, or a vector/array etc. of pair, 
// e.g. something that has enum in .first and string in .second

template<typename Container, typename Index>
string toString(Container&& names, Index&& index, const string& noMatch = "NoMatch")
{
    for (auto&& elem : names) {
      if (elem.first == index) {
         return elem.second;
      }
   }
   return noMatch;
}


// Simple example enum
enum class Color
{
    red, green, blue, pink
};

// Example of two converter-container types
constexpr array colors1 = {pair{Color::red, "Red"}, pair{Color::green, "Green"}, pair{Color::blue, "Blue"}};
const map<Color, string> colors2  =  {{Color::red, "Red"}, {Color::green, "Green"}, {Color::blue, "Blue"}};


int main()
{
    cout << toString(colors1, Color::red) << " " << toString(colors2, Color::blue) << " "
     << toString(colors2, Color::pink) << endl;     
}
```

This code works as expected, and prints out "Red Blue NoMatch"

However, I'd like to rewrite the toString function so that it does not return string, but whatever type that is stored in the convert-container (e.g. string, string_view or char*).

If not for the noMatch part, the task would be simple, just to have "auto" instead of "string" as return type:

```
template<typename Container, typename Index>
auto toString(Container&& names, Index&& index)
{
    for (auto&& elem : names) {
      if (elem.first == index) {
         return elem.second;
      }
   }
   return begin(names)->second;
}
```

This works and prints out "Red Blue Red", but is not the solution I am looking for. What I look for is a way to have:

```
template<typename Container, typename Index>
auto toString(Container&& names, Index&& index, const <returnType>& noMatch = "")
{
    for (auto&& elem : names) {
      if (elem.first == index) {
         return elem.second;
      }
   }
   return noMatch;
}
```

But as you see, I need to fill in something for <returnType>, and I have no Idea what it would be.
I can split the function into two different, one for maps and one for array/vector of pairs if that would help, but I would like to be able to keep the same calling syntax.

FWIW, we are currently using gcc 9.2 with c++17 enabled.

Thanks.

Comment: whatever return type is, it has to be the same in all branches. and in your case it's decltype(declval<Container::value_type>().second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deduce the type of `second`, something like:

```
template<typename Container, typename Index,
         typename NoMatchType=decltype(std::declval<typename Container::value_type &&>().second)>
auto toString(Container&& names, Index&& index,
              const NoMatchType &noMatch=NoMatchType{})
```

(You can also use `NoMatchType` instead of `auto` here, if you wish)

Comment: I believe it should be `declval<typename Container::value_type>().second`

Comment: did you `#include <string>` and `#include <utility>` ?

Comment: Thanks both @StPiere and @SamVarshavchik, but neither works. Both suggestions gives error on "declval" saying: `error: 'const std::map<Color, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&' is not a class, struct, or union type`

Comment: you are probably missing `#include <map>`. but it would be easier if you would share godbolt link

Comment: It's possible that my answer needs to be tweaked, however it should be possible for you to figure out the necessary tweaks yourself, if you understand the basic solution shown here. Are you familiar with `declval`, `decltype`, et. al., and what this syntax attempts to do?

Comment: @StPiere Sorry, pretty new here. I think this link works: https://godbolt.org/z/Mv44d4

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am a bit over my head when it comes to declval and decltype, though I have a rough idea.

Comment: Ok, so, this is a learning experience. Just take it slowly, and use your C++ textbook as a reference. The shown code in your question is incomplete, just partial code fragments. Similarly, the only answers you'll get, therefore, will be based on partial, incomplete code samples that you will need to adapt to your real code. The general idea is to add an additional template parameter, with a default value that deduces what your `returnType` should be, based on the container type that's the first template parameter.

Comment: You forgot to set the type of the third parameter (like I did in my answer), properly. I also threw in a `type_traits` and `remove_reference_t`, just for good measure (on second thought, maybe it should be `remove_cvref_t`, that would be something for you to explore, too)... https://godbolt.org/z/1r3MoP

Comment: Thanks for a working solution @SamVarshavchik :-) Unfortunately I am to new to upvote your answers. I use your reply and test out various combinations and try to learn as much as possible from it. :-D

Comment: You can mark the answer as "accepted" first, and after taking the [tour] and reading the [help], you might get enough rep to upvote answers.

Comment: Thanks. I made one change to your solution, moving the complicated part out from the template<...> part and directly into the parameter type of the noMatch variable: [link](https://godbolt.org/z/dcdqvb). That way the optional argument would not interfer with the actual return value. In my updated code there would be compilation error in line 42 without the change.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this improvement over @Sam answer, but it comes down to the same thing:

Instead of a third template argument (which complicates your interface and locks it down against later easy extensions), you can use some relatively easy to understand type traits to achieve what you want.
Instead of that `decltype`/`std::declval` syntax which is a bit heavy for what it wants to do, i.e. get the type of the second part of the `Container`'s `value_type`. We can use `pair`'s `TupleLike` qualities to simplify this:

```
template<typename Container, typename Index>
auto toString(Container&& names, Index&& index,
              const std::tuple_element_t<1, typename Container::value_type>& noMatch = {})
```

Note I left out the repetition of the "heavy" parameter type (it was already unnecessary in the original version).
If you know you're only going to use `MapLike` types for `Container`, you can take a shortcut and use its type aliases directly:

```
template<typename Container, typename Index>
auto toString(Container&& names, Index&& index,
              const typename Container::mapped_type& noMatch = {})
```

Comment: Thanks  @rubenvb. I got your above solution to work, after a bit of effort (which is good, as this is as much of a learning experience as anything else): https://godbolt.org/z/6aYTs7
What I needed to do was 1) to use remove_reference_t on Container - and then to count from 0 instead of 1 - thus changing the index from 2 to 1 in the usage of tuple_element_t ;-)

Comment: Ah yes, the index was my mistake, sorry about that. The `remove_reference_t ` is necessary because you use `Container&&` which is deduced (and not wrong or anything!) but it would be deduced differently had you used e.g. `const Container&` and then the `remove_reference_t` wouldn't be necessary. The more experience you get with these things, the better you can solve the issues you face when writing this kind of code. You might be able to avoid some problems, but problems you will keep having. Glad you could learn out of this!